# Time and Material Reporting - Process to combine multiple columns and rows of different data types

Tags: php, mysql, database, multiple-columns

I am quite new to MySql (3 months of YouTube tutorials) and most of my experience comes from PHP/HTML(4-5 years building websites) and I am trying to build a report for some data that I've started collecting.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

I have a MySql database that collects multiple columns of materials/products that correspond to a quantity of material that was used on a construction site.

The data currently look like this:

`Material1    | Quantity1 | Material2    | Quantity2 | Material3   | Quantity3|`
`Concrete Bags| 35        | Hydroseed    | 1300      | Diesel Fuel | 40       |`
`Straw Wattles| 32        | Wooden Stakes| 200       | Diesel Fuel | 30       |`
`Hydroseed    | 1000      | Wooden Stakes| 100       | Diesel Fuel | 20       |`

---

What query or process can I use to add the quantities of same name materials, and combine the material names?

`Hydroseed has two entries, 1300 + 1000 = 2300; Diesel Fuel has three entries, 40 + 30 + 20 = 90; etc.` `Material1, Material2, Material3 = MaterialName`

I want to display it in the following manner: 
`MaterialName  | Quantity |`
`Concrete Bags | 35       |`
`Hydroseed     | 2300     |`
`Straw Wattles | 32       |`
`Wooden Stakes | 300      |`
`Diesel Fuel   | 90       |`

I am not exactly sure how to approach this.

My current query looks like this:

`("SELECT Material1 AS MaterialName FROM table UNION SELECT Material2 AS MaterialName FROM table UNION SELECT Material3 AS MaterialName FROM database GROUP BY MaterialName");`

I do not know what to do with the Quantities - I do not know how to combine the two queries and have the totals match up with the correct material name - perhaps something of this sort:

`("SELECT *, SUM(Quantity1 + Quantity2 + Quantity3) AS Quantity FROM table GROUP BY MaterialName");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do an aggregation over a union of the three types of column data:

```
SELECT material AS MaterialName, SUM(quantity) AS Quantity
FROM
(
    SELECT Material1 AS material, Quantity1 AS quantity FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Material2, Quantity2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Material3, Quantity3 FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY material;
```

The basic strategy here is to bring the three pairs of material data into just two columns.  Then, aggregate by material and find the sum of quantity, for each material.

[image]

### Demo

By the way, your current data model is not good, and in general you should not be storing the same logical thing across multiple columns.  Consider just having two columns, one for the material and the other for the quantity.

Comment: What would be a good way to structure that in the database/table? Currently the data is collected from a web form that looks similar to the image you linked, the materials and quantities are submitted to a single table as a one row with the columns as TicketNumber(primary key), Date, Material1, Quantity1, Material2, Quantity2, Material3, Quantity3 - if you know any articles that can guide me too, I would appreciate it. Thank you for your help too, your solution worked!

Comment: Your table should look like the image in my answer.